# MappedByteBuffer not releasing memory

Tags: java

I am having trouble using the NIO MappedByteBuffer function to read very large seismic files. The format my program reads is called SEGY and consists of seismic data samples as well as meta data regarding, among other items, the numeric ID and XY coordinates of the seismic data.

The structure of the format is fairly fixed with a 240 byte header followed by a fixed number of data samples making up each seismic trace. The number of samples per trace can vary from file to file but usually is around 1000 to 2000.

Samples can be written as single bytes, 16 or 32 bit integers, or either IBM or IEEE float. The data in each trace header can likewise be in any of the above formats. To further confuse the issue SEGY files can be in big or little endian byte order.

The files can range in size from 3600 bytes up to several terrabytes.

My application is a SEGY editor and viewer. For many of the functions it performs I must read only one or two variables, say long ints from each trace header.

At present I am reading from a RandomAccessFile into a byte buffer, then extracting the needed variables from a view buffer. This works but is painfully slow for very large files.

I have written a new file handler using a mapped byte buffer that breaks the file into 5000 trace MappedByteBuffers. This works well and is very fast until my system runs low on memory and then it slows to a crawl and I am forced to reboot just to make my Mac useable again.

For some reason the memory from the buffers is never released, even after my program is finished. I need to either do a purge or reboot.

This is my code. Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

```
package MyFileHandler;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.*;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyFileHandler
{

    /*
    A buffered file IO class that keeps NTRACES traces in memory for reading and writing. 
    the buffers start and end at trace boundaries and the buffers are sequential
    i.e  1-20000,20001-40000, etc
    The last, or perhaps only buffer will contain less than NTRACES up to the last trace
    The arrays  BufferOffsets and BufferLengths contain the start and length for all the 
    buffers required to read and write to the file
     */

    private static int NTRACES = 5000;
    private boolean HighByte;
    private long FileSize;
    private int BytesPerTrace;
    private FileChannel FileChnl;
    private MappedByteBuffer Buffer;
    private long BufferOffset;
    private int BufferLength;
    private long[] BufferOffsets;
    private int[] BufferLengths;
    private RandomAccessFile Raf;
    private int BufferIndex;
    private ArrayList Maps;


    public MyFileHandler(RandomAccessFile raf, int bpt)
    {
        try
        {
            HighByte = true;
            //      allocate a filechannel to the file
            FileChnl = raf.getChannel();
            FileSize = FileChnl.size();
            BytesPerTrace = bpt;
            SetUpBuffers();
            BufferIndex = 0;
            GetNewBuffer(0);
        } catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void SetUpBuffers()
    {
    // get number of traces in entire file
        int ntr = (int) ((FileSize - 3600) / BytesPerTrace);

        int nbuffs = ntr / NTRACES;
        //  add one to nbuffs unless filesize is multiple of NTRACES
        if (Math.IEEEremainder(ntr, NTRACES) != 0)
        {
            nbuffs++;
        }
        BufferOffsets = new long[nbuffs];
        BufferLengths = new int[nbuffs];
        // BuffOffset are in bytes, not trace numbers
        //get the offsets and lengths of each buffer
        for (int i = 0; i < nbuffs; i++)
        {
            if (i == 0)
            {
            //  first buffer contains EBCDIC header 3200 bytes and binary header 400 bytes
                BufferOffsets[i] = 0;
                BufferLengths[i] = 3600 + (Math.min(ntr, NTRACES) * BytesPerTrace);
            } else
            {
                BufferOffsets[i] = BufferOffsets[i - 1] + BufferLengths[i - 1];
                BufferLengths[i] = (int) (Math.min(FileSize - BufferOffsets[i], NTRACES * BytesPerTrace));
            }
        }
        GetMaps();

    }
    private void GetMaps()
    {
    //  map the file to list of MappedByteBuffer
        Maps = new ArrayList(BufferOffsets.length);
        try
        {
            for(int i=0;i<BufferOffsets.length;i++)
            {
                MappedByteBuffer map = FileChnl.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, BufferOffsets[i], BufferLengths[i]);
                SetByteOrder(map);
                Maps.add(map);
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    private void GetNewBuffer(long offset)
    {
        if (Buffer == null || offset < BufferOffset || offset >= BufferOffset + BufferLength)
        {
            BufferIndex = GetBufferIndex(offset);
            BufferOffset = BufferOffsets[BufferIndex];
            BufferLength = BufferLengths[BufferIndex];
            Buffer = (MappedByteBuffer)Maps.get(BufferIndex);
        }
    }
    private int GetBufferIndex(long offset)
    {
        int indx = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < BufferOffsets.length; i++)
        {
           if (offset >= BufferOffsets[i] && offset < BufferOffsets[i]+BufferLengths[i])
            {
                indx = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return indx;
    }

    private void SetByteOrder(MappedByteBuffer ByteBuff)
    {
        if (HighByte)
        {
            ByteBuff.order(ByteOrder.BIG_ENDIAN);
        } else
        {
            ByteBuff.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
        }
    }
    //  public methods to read, (get) or write (put) an array of types, byte, short, int, or float. 
    //  for sake of brevity only showing get and put for ints

    public void Get(int[] buff, long offset)
    {
        GetNewBuffer(offset);
        Buffer.position((int) (offset - BufferOffset));
        Buffer.asIntBuffer().get(buff);
    }


    public void Put(int[] buff, long offset)
    {
        GetNewBuffer(offset);
        Buffer.position((int) (offset - BufferOffset));
        Buffer.asIntBuffer().put(buff);
    }

    public void HighByteOrder(boolean hb)
    {
        //  all byte swapping is done by the buffer class
        //  set all allocated buffers to same byte order
        HighByte = hb;

    }

    public int GetBuffSize()
    {
        return BufferLength;
    }

    public void Close()
    {

        try
        {
            FileChnl.close();
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a condition that you might be doing a return statement before calling the Close method?

Comment: Here's some background on release of mapped buffers: http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=4724038

Answer (score 0):

You are mapping the entire file into memory, via a possibly large number of `MappedByteBuffers`, and as you are keeping them in a `Map` they are never released. It is pointless. You may as well map the entire file with a *single* `MappedByteBuffer`, or the minimum number you need to overcome the address limitation. There is no benefit in using more of them than you need.

But I would only map the segment of the file that is *currently* being viewed/edited, and release it when the user moves to another segment.

I'm surprised that `MappedByteBuffer` is found to be so much faster. Last time I tested, reads via mapped byte buffers were only 20% faster than `RandomAccessFile`, and writes not at all. I'd like to see the `RandomAccessFile` code, as it seems there is probably something wrong with it that could easily be fixed.

Comment: Do you know on how to release MappedByteBuffers under Android?